# What happened to my close vote?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I've been watching the Cisco tag over the last few weeks, routinely voting to close the off-topic questions that appear there. Some weeks ago it seems I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25497989/1864610), but revisiting it today I discover that there's no sign of any close votes, yet when I go to vote again I'm told I've already voted.

What happened to my vote?

As an aside, there are an increasing number of questions languishing on the Cisco tag that don't seem to receive any attention. Many of them are clearly off-topic. What's the best way to tidy them up?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Close votes age away if no further votes come in. [Jeff Atwood lays out the original rules on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97581/159251):

Once there are more than one hundred views on the question, close votes start expiring four days after the last one was cast.

On top of that, [a vote only lasts for fourteen days after being cast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/165773) if the question is still open. (This is regardless of views.) Fourteen days after it ages away, however, **the vote can be recast**, thus [status-completing] the feature request [Please allow expired close/open votes to be re-cast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99333/please-allow-expired-close-open-votes-to-be-re-cast?lq=1).

(For completeness, the same fourteen-day expiry and re-eligibility applies to reopen votes as well.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Josh. I've upvoted the feature request. It seems there is a balance to be struck here between closing too many question with long-lived close votes, or leaving off-topic questions with too few votes languishing.

Answer (score 17):

Answering the aside:

You can always drop in the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chatroom and leave a

`[tag:cv-pls] http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276866/what-happened-to-my-close-vote`

message, for example [this one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=19117882#19117882). Regulars in that room will judge your request and if they see fit they follow your vote. As an extra benefit that same message will be re-posted in the QA chatrooms on MSE Chat.

<sub>Don't forget to join our weekly events where we handle the CVQ, users with close vote privileges are  welcome....</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the link - I didn't know that room existed. I could be busy there.

Comment: Yeah, that link is awesome.  Is there a Delete Vote Reviewers chatroom as well?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables No, but I'm happy to help out

Answer (score 4):

> What's the best way to tidy them up?

I don't think there is a way. I've given up on doing that sort of cleanup, because 95% of the time, the system just comes along and deletes the votes. Apparently, the close-vote queue is so overloaded, that the only way they could deal with it was to delete close votes. That way they can pretend the number of questions that need closing is smaller than it is. Of course, there wouldn't be so many questions in the queue needing close votes if the system didn't keep deleting the close votes.

In many cases, the close and reopen buttons are simply placebo buttons. You place the vote and go off thinking you've done something useful, but if you come back to the question later you find out that all you've done is wasted your time, because the system has deleted your vote and blocked you from voting to close or reopen that question again.

---

Edit: I guess I get the theory... that if a question isn't getting close or reopen votes at a certain rate, it probably doesn't need to be closed or reopened. If they didn't delete old votes at all, then any question would *eventually* accumulate 5 votes, even if only from accidental clicks. But it seems to me that the balance is *way* off.

Just brainstorming here.. It doesn't help the situation that there is no way to un-close-vote. You can vote 'leave open' only if you somehow hunt the question down by trawling the review history, not from a question page itself. If close/open votes were on a simple sliding scale like up/down votes are (with a little bit of hysteresis around the threshold level to prevent rapid fluctuation between the 'closed' and 'open' states) then any wrong close vote could be reversed by someone else voting 'open'. Without that, the system has to have some mechanism for automatically deleting votes, and currently that mechanism is badly mistuned.

<sup>(Didn't mean to make this community wiki, oops.)</sup>

Comment: I admit, most of my close votes get used in the 10k Moderators' Tools close vote list. That has the advantages that reviewing questions is easy, and my vote immediately closes a question.

Comment: @MikeW I did that for a bit, then I stopped because I got worried that by voting to close the obvious questions, the next ones that would bubble up that list would be the ones that actually shouldn't be closed, and then they would be more likely to be closed by someone else. Some of the questions on that list I would like to vote "no, keep that one open", but there is no way to do it. A hundred people could look at a question and want it left open, but if only 5 see it and decide they don't like the look of it, it's zapped. The choices then seem to be "close it" or "let someone else close it".