# Do Votes timeout? How to effectively vote on old questions then?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, old-questions, vote-to-reopen

Recently I stumpled across this question:
[Difference between Thread.yield() and Thread.sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048170/difference-between-thread-yield-and-thread-sleep)

The question is about Java as indicated in the tags and it also has Java based answers which make sense. All in all this seems to be a perfectly legit question. However it is marked as a duplicate to this question: [Difference between Thread.Sleep(0) and Thread.Yield()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956961/difference-between-thread-sleep0-and-thread-yield)

While the second question sounds similar, the second question is about .NET and not about Java, they just happened to have methods that have the same name and also do something similar. So I disagree that these questions are duplicates. If the first question is a duplicate then rather of this question: [Are Thread.sleep(0) and Thread.yield() statements equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600572/are-thread-sleep0-and-thread-yield-statements-equivalent). IMHO it is confusing to find this question on google, then checking out the "duplicate", wondering about the answers and than noticing that the question is about another language.

I assumed that this was done by error and cast a reopen vote. To bad that the vote cannot be accompanied by a comment, so I put a comment directly on the question and thought that this will go its way and eventually there will be enough votes to reopen the question.

However now, about 6 weeks later, not only no new reopen votes occured, but my vote seems to have "vanished". I searched whether votes do timeout on stackoverflow, but I did not find anything about that. So I wonder what happened. Did the vote timeout? If it did, then it seems rather pointless to vote on old questions that will only slowly get more views by people willing to vote. What should I do in such cases? Ignore it? Or was I wrong with my repopen-vote in the first place?

Comment: It went through the [reopen queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12332072) and it was decided to leave it closed.

Comment: @Floern: How would I find the queue? (Except for knowing the URL pattern and constructing ist now that you told me?) (you could post this as an answer, maybe with an interpretation what we should learn from this)

Comment: On the SOCVR github, theres a userscript that adds a link to the post's timeline which shows all of the completed reviews.

Comment: As for the more general case question in the title: Yes, [close votes do age away eventually](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276867/5240004).

Comment: If the question is good and not a duplicate, just pose it yourself (after all by reopening you won't help the original asker anyway).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The questions went through the [reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12332072)<sup>1</sup> and the reviewers decided to leave it closed (3 *reopen* vs 3 *leave closed*). Thus the reopen votes faded away. It would have needed just one more vote to reopen it.

The close voters probably missed that the other question is for another programming language. Although if the question and answers are identical for both languages, it may be valid to have it closed as a cross-language duplicate.

If you really think it needs to be reopened and possibly be re-closed as a duplicate of another question, you may ask in the [SOCVR chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) ([FAQ](http://so-close-vote-reviewers.github.io/faq)) for assistance.

<sub>1: You can find the link to the queue in the question's [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15048170/timeline), whose URL you have to construct from the question ID (or use a [user script](https://github.com/Tunaki/stackoverflow-userscripts/blob/master/showtimeline.user.js) that adds the link to the question).</sub>