# Why is my vote to close a question no longer shows under "close" and cannot revote?

Tags: support, questions, vote-to-close

I voted to close the following question as a typo:

- [Fatal Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356757/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-pdostatementprepare)

But my vote (and possibly others, if there were others; I can't remember) isn't showing as "1" (or more) under "close".

I don't remember retracting my vote and that does not appear in there neither.

I have seen: *"You have already voted to close this question, but you may vote again in 6 days"* under the popup dialog box, which indicates that I did in fact voted to close.

The following shows up at the bottom right of that dialog box:

- "You voted to close this question Apr 11 at 21:58".

I also found the following Q&A's but can't seem to see the relation with the question I am asking:

- [Bogus "You have already voted to close this question" on expired votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99141/bogus-you-have-already-voted-to-close-this-question-on-expired-votes)
- [Age close votes after 14 days, regardless of views, allowing recasting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting)

Can someone shed some light on this for me please? I'm a bit puzzled.

Here are a few screenshots:

**My vote to close not showing:**

[image]

**An example of a number showing under "close" for another question I voted to close today:**

[image]

**Popup dialog:**

[image]

---

**Edit:**

The possible duplicate that my question was flagged/marked as

[What happened to my close vote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276866/what-happened-to-my-close-vote)

states: *"On top of that, a vote only lasts for fourteen days after being cast if the question is still open."* - [The question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43356757/1415724) is still open and my vote to close is more than 14 days old and that screenshot I took of the dialog box was taken earlier today, as was my trying to recast a new vote. So, why can't I recast the same or another vote to close?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120896/why-do-close-votes-expire

Comment: @HansPassant I see, thank you. This *"The system has actually been reworked recently to take into account low-traffic beta sites"* - as shown under the accepted answer mentions about "beta sites". Do you know if that is/was specific to only beta sites or it is (now) using the same method throughout the entire network, be it beta or not?

Comment: *"You voted to close this question Apr 11"* - so yes your vote expired by now.

Comment: @Gimby If the vote had expired he'd be able to re-cast it.

Comment: @Gimby Yes, I noticed that after reading though the link that Hans provided and I responded to it, if you can have a look.

Comment: @servy not according to one of the overmeta links that was provided in the question (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99141/268911). However, that is from years ago so perhaps things should have changed.

Comment: and the thing about *"to take into account low-traffic beta sites"* in that answer is kind of unclear. Stack isn't "beta" (anymore). Either that answer needs to be updated or something else be done because I am getting more and more puzzled.

Comment: @gnat https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276867/1415724 states: *"On top of that, a vote only lasts for fourteen days after being cast if the question is still open."* - [The question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43356757/1415724) is still open and my vote to close is more than 14 days and that screenshot I took of the dialog box was taken earlier today. So, why can't I recast the same or another vote to close?

Comment: @Fred-ii- You only get one close and one reopen vote per question.  After you use it, even if it ages away, your done.

Comment: @NathanOliver *"After you use it, even if it ages away, your done."* - [The answer}(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276867/1415724) also states: *"Fourteen days after it is deleted, however, **the vote can be recast**"*, yet you say I am "done". Either that answer is incorrect or there's something not playing ball somewhere.

Comment: systems requires wait for 14 days _after_ your vote aged away. Since question has less than 100 views your vote was there for 14 days until expiry. Together that makes `2*14=28` days break before you can cast it again - 14 days for your vote to hang there before expiry plus another 14 days after it has expired (as a prolific close voter I memorized this breakdown by blood from my heart)

Comment: Yep.  gnat is right.  Cool to learn though you do get them back if they age away.

Comment: @gnat *Plus* another 14 on top of 14? I see. I guess there's something I wasn't quite grasping then. Ok thanks for clarifying that for me. +1

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, gnat was right and am glad that it was clarified. Well, I for one don't hang around questions for 28 days *lol*. I only noticed the question in question when the OP [posted a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43784708/1415724) where I noticed the comment under it about their last post and the duplicate it was closed with. Upon visiting [that other one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43356757/1415724) is when I noticed that my close vote was gone as was my ability to revote.