# Is this question on topic for main SO site?

Tags: support, specific-question, scope

Five days ago, I downvoted and close voted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48180620/5468463) as off-topic with the reason that I don't see how it is addressing a programming issue directly. It has three answers also far from programming topic.

Today I can see that my close vote was invalidated.

Do you think the question is on topic? If so, why? If not, what should be done?

Comment: This question is off topic, it should be downvoted, closed and maybe deleted.

I already voted to close, hopefully other users will do that soon.

Comment: What do you mean with _"the flag was cleared"_?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48180620/timeline the timeline doesnt show anything

Comment: @SurajRao it shows an invalidated close review. I don't call that *doesn't show anything*

Comment: @Vega Me neither. I'm voting to delete now.

Comment: Can you check if the close vote is found on https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=closure

Comment: So its not a flag.. you close voted. @rene right. I got a bit confused when OP said their flag got cleared

Comment: Also it seems someone marked it as spam. I dont think it is...

Comment: MSE related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279565/158100

Comment: Yes I mod flagged to remove the flag.

Comment: @SurajRao I did. For me it seems like it could be promoting a product.

Comment: @Maroun not really. OP seems to have a genuine question (offtopic and  maybe customer support query). They havent posted any links nor is there any history of that project in OP's profile to tie to the product

Comment: @Maroun it linked to an image hosted on stacks own imgur. Had they linked to the webshop, sure.

Comment: @rene Ah, I thought it was linked to a store. But still, it could be promoting the product itself.

Comment: @Maroun please be careful with spam flags, those have significant impact on posters :D

Comment: @Maroun and not to mention bad review audits :p

Comment: For some reason, the post was undeleted...

Comment: @Vega it restores the votes, no upvotes have been cast on that question.

Comment: @Vega I see an upvote on the 23rd of Feb on the timeline

Comment: I missed a single upvote, thanks @WhatsThePoint

Comment: I whaced the mole down again.  Since it's about hardware, I can't imagine any reason for it being on-topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not on-topic so you did The Right Thing™ and so did the close and delete voters. A moderator had to clear a spam flag which caused an undelete of the post but another 3 delete voters rectified that. Otherwise the Roomba would have got to it in 10 days.

Your close vote triggered the creation of a close vote review but as that didn't get any reviewers in 4 days, it was invalidated. I speculate that that caused the *close (1)* to be restored to a plain *close* causing you to believe your close vote was cleared.

However, it takes a bit longer for a close vote to age away, 14 days to be precise as is explained in [What happened to my close vote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276866/what-happened-to-my-close-vote). You can check your close votes in your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=closure) but it doesn't show if they are invalidated or not.

If you run into a question that is on low traffic tags (anything not in PHP or RegEx) that needs close votes you better seek assistance in chat (for example [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) but check their [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq) first) instead of solely relying on reviewers, as that close vote queue never gets cleared in 6 to 8 weeks (where are you reviewers?).

Comment: I think you forgot the option to post it on meta like for example this exact question.

Comment: @AndréKool I thought about that but I don't want to substitute the close vote queue with meta. The problem remains: there are not enough users spending their close votes. So I'm not editing that in as *general advice*. The occasional success story is fine.

Comment: @rene - I cleared a spam flag on that post which undeleted the post. As the question was already put on hold, I didn't delete it. No qualms about it being deleted later though, it wasn't adding any value.